# yii - action render a view after ajax request but the view is not show in browser

Tags: php, html, ajax, yii

A part of my code where this problem occur get following logic:

The view1 get some information with links. when a user click a link X, a post request is send to a controller on XAMPP web server to open the view2 from the link X. Furthermore all append in yii framework and  I am new in this.

HTML view1:

```
 <a id="article-title1" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Js:

```
function myFunction()
{
  alert('allo my function');
      dataString = "hallo";
      $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"http://localhost/basic/web/example/hello",
          data:{'dataString':dataString},
          success:function (data) {
             console.log("send success");
          }
      });
}
```

controller:

```
public function actionHello() {

        $nom = "david";
        $prenom = "pascal";

        return $this->render('information',[
            'name' => $nom,
            'prenom' => $prenom
        ]);

    }
```

php view2:

```
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = 'information';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class = "site-information">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <p>
        This is the information page
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>name:</b><?= $name ?>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>firstname:</b><?= $firstname ?>
    </p>
    <code><?= __FILE__ ?></code>
</div>
```

moreover  there ajax url(http://localhost/basic/web/example/hello) in browser work fine. But I don't know why the render of view2 is don't showed in browser after receiving the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

When you sending ajax request, always you need to return something to web browser. In this case, you need to return a rendered html on a server side, to client and replace old html for newest with js.

Comment: do you mean to make a reload of a page when ajax succed ? i don 't understand when you say "replace old html for newest with js."